# Возвращаемый тип при вызове лямбды, захватывающей параметр по значению

Tags: c++, gcc, лямбда-выражение

Какой возвращаемый тип будет при вызове этой лямбды? Можно ли узнать это каким-то программным способом? Пробовал `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, но не показывает ничего полезного.

```
int main() {
    int x,y;
    [=,&y] -> decltype((x)) {
        return y;
    };
}
```

Comment: возвращаемый тип - `decltype((x))` А вообще мне кажется, что тут пропущен кусок

Comment: `std::cout << typeid(([=,&y] -> decltype((x)) {
        return y;
    })()).name() << '\n';` => `i` , то есть **int**

Comment: @AlexGlebe `typeid` обрезает константность и ссылочность.

Comment: Судя по отсутствию `()`, это `-std=c++2b`. Значит, `const int&`. См. https://wg21.link/p2036.

Comment: (Когда реализуют это предложение в `gcc`.)